# bash - echo negation

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

```bsh
echo ${string##*.}   # this will show everything after last "."
```

How can i revert (negate) this - show everything before last "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${string%.*}` will remove the shortest trailing portion matching `.*`

See for example [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) in the excellent [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)